# Python unable to locate object attribute

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

So, I wanted to create an A* Pathfinding visualiser with python which instantiates an object 'Cell' which is basically every coordinate of a 2D array called 'Grid' with a method that changes the colour of a Cell and another that adds neighbours. However, when i call the methods, I get the error:

Exception has occured: AttributeError
'int' object has no attribute 'drawCell'

This error occurs on the last line 
`grid[0][i].drawCell((0, 0, 0), 0)`

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.i = x
        self.j = y
        self.f = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.neighbours = []
        self.parent = None

    def drawCell(self, color, filled):
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen, [red, blue, green], [left, top, width, height], filled)
        pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, color, [self.i * cellW, self.j * cellH, cellW, cellH], filled)
        pygame.display.update()

rows = 30
columns = 30
grid = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]
cellW = 500 / columns
cellH = 500 / rows
cellCost = 1 

for i in range(columns):
    for j in range(rows):
        grid[i][j] = Cell(i, j)
        grid[i][j].drawCell((255, 255, 255), True)

for i in range(0,rows):
    grid[0][i].drawCell((0, 0, 0), 0)
    ....
```

I'm very new to python and wanted to gain experience on using modules for GUI so help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error means that at some point `grid[0][j]` got set to an integer. It may have been done in the code you cut off at the end. I would recommend adding print statements in the last for loop that prints 1 each iteration, so you can see how many times it makes it through the loop before crashing.

Comment: Can't reproduce error with the code as stated. However, the error is telling you that `grid[0][i]` is type `int`, whereas obviously to call the `drawCell` method, you need it to be an instance of `Cell`.   You can use `print(type(grid[0][i]))` in a few places to debug where this is happening.